# How to use periods in c++ namespaces?

Tags: c#, c++, namespaces, interop

I'm trying to call a c# managed assembly *Qqest.TimeForce.Facade.dll*, from c++ code, and my class looks like the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "Qqest.TimeForce.Facade.dll"

using namespace Qqest.TimeForce.Facade;

void CreateOdcEmployeeTemplateWrapMethod(int employeeId, int templateType)
{
    Qqest.TimeForce.Facade::WebFacade::CreateOdcEmployeeTemplate(employeeId, templateType);
}
```

The compiler is complaining about line 5, I don't think it likes the periods in the namespace, but I don't know a way around this.

EDIT: Sorry, here is the exact error:  "error C2059: syntax error : '.'" on line 5

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm assuming it's because "The compiler is complaining" is absolutely useless to us. Is it giving an error? If so, which error? Is it blowing up? Spitting out waffles? What exactly is it doing?

Comment: Oops, sorry @Doorknob, updated the question with the error

Comment: @Doorknob D'oh - multiple tabs, wrong windows, wrong comment :)  removed...

Comment: @LB2 Heh, that's happened to me a few times :)

Comment: Use `::` instead of `.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change statement

```
using namespace Qqest.TimeForce.Facade;
```

to

```
using namespace Qqest::TimeForce::Facade;
```